# How to determine if a wordList contains one of the substrings of a phrase in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

I have a List stopWord(each string is only one word) and I have a string phrases(at least 2 words). I want to check if my phrases includes one of the stopWord's element in Java. How can I do that?

```
if(!stopWord.contains(phrase.toLowerCase())
String delims = "[ ,-.…•“”‘’:;!()/?\"]+";
```

I used this code but I think it doesn't understand String with 2 words which is my phrase. stopWord's each element is single word. I didn't split my phrase. Cuz I'm dealing with large amount of data. Is there a simplier way?

Comment: What have you tried? Can we see some code? What is the delimiter for your `phrases` between the words?

Comment: indexOf method will do the trick.

Comment: Yup you are close.  We have to parse out your `phrases` so when we call the `contains()` method we only check one word.  What is the delimiter in your `phrases`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String[] words = phrase.split(" ");
    for (String word : words)
    {
        if (stopWord.contains(word))
        {
            // do here whatever you need :)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Btw phrases is a String it is not a list

Comment: @FatihAktepe: edited, and added a new response, in case.

Comment: previus solution is efficient. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8:

```
String phrase = "your phrase";
if (stopWord.parallelStream().anyMatch(s -> phrase.contains(s)))
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I'm using Java 8 . I'll check your solution and update the question. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't worked exactly the way I wanted but it is okey. I'll can handle the problem from here. Thanks a lot for help.